# Non tilt window not coming out

Tags: windows

I’m trying to troubleshoot why my non tilt window is very difficult to raise and lower.

I did some research and some information gathering. My windows were installed in 1986. They are non tilt windows. I learned about take out clips and how I can use those to take off the window and maybe replace some clips or channel.

However, I’m having a little trouble getting my window off track. After I push window passed the clip, it ejects a little but not all the way. I try to slide window to left and it’s almost loose but not. Maybe the house has settled some but it’s just barely hanging on to it.

I can get either the top edge or bottom edge passed the frame but not both at same time where window comes out.

Has anyone come across this before? I feel like with a little force it would come out or… shatter from the pressure.

Comment: Please add photos - a general picture of the window and close-ups of any relevant hardware, IE springs, pulleys, latches, etc.  You can Press "Edit" above and copy-paste pictures or use the Image tool in the editor.

Comment: Picture would help showing the problem area.  Enough force and too much usually a fine line.  Someone here might see what you are missing.